# Discrepancy in the number of files

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder in which there are 672 jpg files and a corresponding csv file which contains data related to those image files. The problem is that csv file contains 709 records so there must be some corresponding image files missing from the folder.

I tried this Python script which should be able to tell me which files are missing

```
import csv
import os
import glob

i = 1
j = 0
k = 0

with open('points.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print "missing files"
    for row in reader:
        if not os.path.isfile("img_resize/" + str(row[1])):
            print row[1], i
            k = k + 1
        i = i + 1        
            

for filename in glob.iglob('img_resize/*.jpg'):
    j = j + 1
    
print "total files in folder ", j
print "total files in csv ", i
```

The output of the program is

> missing files
>
> name 1
>
> w_7489.jpg 574
>
> total files in folder  672
>
> total files in csv  710

The first line of csv is a header so if we take that into account then there are 709 records in csv, 672 image files in the folder. But the only missing file is "w_7489.jpg" which is actually missing as I've checked that manually.

My question is that why the program is unable to locate other 36 missing files?

Comment: Are there temporary or hidden files in the folder.

Comment: maybe records are repeated

Comment: Or duplicate names in the CSV? You can obviously only have one file with each name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could update your test script to add a Python [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#counter-objects) to count the occurrences of each of your files in the CSV file as follows:

```
from collections import Counter
import csv
import os
import glob

i = 1
k = 0
file_counts = Counter()

with open('points.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print "missing files"
    for row in reader:  
        file_counts.update([row[1]])
        if not os.path.isfile("img_resize/" + str(row[1])):
            print row[1], i
            k += 1
        i += 1

j = len(list(glob.iglob('img_resize/*.jpg')))

print "total files in folder ", j
print "total files in csv ", i
print
print "duplicates"

for filename, count in file_counts.items(): 
    if count > 1:
        print count, filename
```

This will then display if any of the files are stored more than once. If you are running on Windows, you might want to store a lowercase version.

Comment: It worked! I'm new to Python so I didn't know about Counter. There were 35 duplicates in total. Thank you so much.